# Writing "m-dash" and "n-dash" in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, special-characters, tcpdf

I am trying to solve a few problems with the pdf-converter-plugin (POST2PDF, based on TCPDF) on my wordpress-based homepage.

The plugin automatically creates a header for every pdf based on the page-title. I want it to cut the title before specific characters like "?", ":" and especially before m-dash and n-dash. But I can't figure out how to write m-dash and n-dash so the plugin will accept it. I already tried html and the Unicode but to no avail.

This is the part of code I have written, X marks the spot for m-dash or n-dash:

```
$i = 0;
    for (;$orgtitle[$i] != "X" and $i < mb_strlen($orgtitle, 'UTF-8');)
        {$i = ++$i; }

    if ($i == mb_strlen($orgtitle, 'UTF-8'))
    {   $header_title = $title;}
    else {
    $header_title = substr($orgtitle, 0, --$i);
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how about you just use `strpos` instead of your loop that would amaze me if it even works

Comment: The loop works with other characters at least. 'strpos' seems to be less messy than my loop but do you think it will solve the issue of php not recognizing special characters?

Comment: Interestingly enough using `strpos` solved the problem! Thank you so much!